# How to read the client_key of a ZAP authenticated peer using clrzmq4?

Tags: c#, zeromq

The goal I am trying to achieve is to have a unique id per connected peer (without the peer having to set it themselves - I don't want to trust user provided input!). I am using `CURVE` and `ZAP` to authenticate clients. Each client has it's own key pair, which means every client has a unique `client_key` associated to it. I know that a client has a `client_key` associated because it is printed to stdout when passing the `VERBOSE` option to the `ZAP` handler. Basically, I am using the [ironhouse example](https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq4/blob/master/ZGuideExamples/ironhouseserver.cs) provided by `clrzmq4`.
Here is the output I am referring to:

```
I: zauth: ZAP request mechanism=CURVE ipaddress=127.0.0.1
I: zauth: - allowed (CURVE) client_key=xyRFGwnIzeEWk@tRBISoX-Pe<HDYGJt4!9k&q750
I: zauth: - ZAP reply status_code=200 status_text=OK
```

When receiving a message on this socket, I know that the connected peer is properly authenticated, but I can not tell *who* it is. How do I read the `client_key`? There is a method in the standard ZeroMQ API which is called [zmq_msg_gets](http://api.zeromq.org/4-1:zmq-msg-gets), I found references to it in the [clrzmq4](https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq4/blob/master/Platform/zmq.cs#L240) project, but I don't know how to use it.

**Edit**:
The ZeroMQ API documentation for [zmq_msg_gets](http://api.zeromq.org/4-1:zmq-msg-gets) specifically states that this message is used to get the zap authenticated user id. See section "Example".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ZFrame` class offers a method called `GetOption`, you can find the definition [here](https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq4/blob/master/ZFrame.cs#L852). The property name has to be "User-Id". Make sure to not use the first frame, that did not work for me (I think this is due to the first frame being the `RouterId`, which is a frame added by the `Router` socket). Assuming your `ZMessage` variable is called "message", you can use the following code to retrieve the User-Id:

```
var userId = message[1].GetOption("User-Id");
```